# Calculate the total number of sign changes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

For each integer i, $1 \leq i \leq 100 ; \varepsilon_{i}$ be either +1 or $-1 .$ Assume that $\varepsilon_{1}=+1$ and $\varepsilon_{100}=-1 .$ Say that a sign change occurs at $i \geq 2$ if
$\varepsilon_{i}, \varepsilon_{i-1}$ are of opposite sign. Then the total number of sign changes

(a) is odd

(b) is even

(c) is at most 50

(d) can have 49 distinct values

*My logic*

$+$ to $+$ sign change is even, as + to – and then
– to +, now, $ԑ_{100}$ is -1. So, number of sign changes must be odd.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you just listed the possibilities when the list is of smaller length, like $4,6,8$?  Did you see a pattern?   The claim that it must be odd is correct.  Clearly $c$ is wrong-can you see that?  The question is whether d is correct.

Comment: option (a) should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, suppose you perform sign change $m$ times.

Then $$-1=\epsilon_{100} = (-1)^m \epsilon_1=(-1)^m$$

$m$ has to be odd.

For example, we can have sign change at every step that is $\epsilon_{2i+1} = 1$ and $\epsilon_{2i}=-1$, in that case we have $99$ sign change.

At the other extreme end, we can have exactly one sign change, say $\epsilon_1=-1$ and $\epsilon_i=1, i \ge 2$, in that case, we can have $1$ sign change.

We can have $\{1,3,5,\ldots, 99\}$, I will leave the computation of the cardinality of the set for you to disprove $(d)$.

Comment: ԑ1 = +1, now it will continue till it gets a -1, if any ԑ is -1 then the
next ԑ will be +1 again because sign change will occur. So, if it gets again -1 then +1 will occur. .....So I think it will be option (a)

Comment: yes $()$,  is correct. try to verify that the other options are not correct as well. –